# Recursive loop to build object

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't figure out how to explain this right, but I wanna make a function that takes this array:

```
const tasks = [
    {id: 1, goal: 'Clean apartment', parent_id: null},
    {id: 2, goal: 'Clean bathroom', parent_id: 1},
    {id: 3, goal: 'Clean kitchen', parent_id: 1},
    {id: 4, goal: 'Clean sink', parent_id: 2},
    {id: 5, goal: 'Clean shower', parent_id: 2},
    {id: 6, goal: 'Make app', parent_id: null}

]
```

and generates this object:

```
{id: 1, goal: 'Clean apartment', parent_id: null, children: [
    {id: 2, goal: 'Clean bathroom', parent_id: 1, children: [
        {id: 4, goal: 'Clean sink', parent_id: 2, children: []},
        {id: 5, goal: 'Clean shower', parent_id: 2, children: []},
    ]},
    {id: 3, goal: 'Clean kitchen', parent_id: 1, children: []},
]},
{id: 6, goal: 'Make app', parent_id: null, children: []}
```

Edit:
So far I made this, but it only returns the first layer of the children:

```
function addChildren(tasks, id) {
    var task = tasks.find(task => task.id === id)
    var children = tasks.filter(task => task.parent_id === id)
    
    task.children = children
    return task
}

var newTask = addChildren(tasks, 1)
console.log(newTask)
```

EDIT 2:
I tried making the function recursive, but I get an error saying "tasks.find is not a function".

```
function addChildren(tasks, id) {
    var task = tasks.find(task => task.id === id)
    var children = tasks.filter(task => task.parent_id === id)
    
    task.children = children
    
    task.children.forEach(child => {
        addChildren(child, child.id)
    })
    return task
}

var newTask = addChildren(tasks, 1)
console.log(newTask)
```

Comment: So make the function! What is stopping you? Can you show us what you tried and tell us where you are stuck?

Comment: I'm trying! I'm stuck on the second layer. I can look up children of the first task, but I'm not able to make the function recursive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code of your attempt. Without that, we can't help you fix it

Comment: Alright, I added the function I've been able to make so far

Comment: Make the function recursive and call it for each child.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried that, but this is where my brain stops working. I added an edit with my updated function and the error I'm getting

Comment: You'd want `addChildren(tasks, child.id)` in the recursive call - the first parameter is still the array of all objects. However, changing your function to accept `child` is not a bad idea - passing the object itself instead of its id means you don't need to `find` the `task` again (except for the root node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the function recursive and call it for each child.

```js
const tasks = [
    {id: 1, goal: 'Clean apartment', parent_id: null},
    {id: 2, goal: 'Clean bathroom', parent_id: 1},
    {id: 3, goal: 'Clean kitchen', parent_id: 1},
    {id: 4, goal: 'Clean sink', parent_id: 2},
    {id: 5, goal: 'Clean shower', parent_id: 2},
    {id: 6, goal: 'Make app', parent_id: null}

]

function addChildren(tasks, idOrTask) {
    var task = (typeof idOrTask === 'number') ? tasks.find(task => task.id === idOrTask) : idOrTask;
    var children = tasks.filter(t => t.parent_id === task.id);
    
    task.children = children.map(child => addChildren(tasks, child));
    return task
}

var newTask = addChildren(tasks, 1)
console.log(newTask)
```

I've optimized the function a little to avoid unnecessary calls of `find`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna take a look at that "map" function!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter those that match a given id, and calculate their children with a recursive call:

```js
const nest = (xs, parent = null) =>
  xs .filter (({parent_id}) => parent_id == parent)
     .map (({id, ...rest}) => ({id, ...rest, children: nest (xs, id)}))
 

const tasks = [{id: 1, goal: 'Clean apartment', parent_id: null}, {id: 2, goal: 'Clean bathroom', parent_id: 1}, {id: 3, goal: 'Clean kitchen', parent_id: 1}, {id: 4, goal: 'Clean sink', parent_id: 2}, {id: 5, goal: 'Clean shower', parent_id: 2}, {id: 6, goal: 'Make app', parent_id: null}]

console .log (nest (tasks))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you no longer want the now-redundant `parent_id` in the output, you can simply remove it by replacing the `map` line above with:

```js
    .map (({id, parent_id, ...rest}) => ({id, ...rest, children: nest (xs, id)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tasks = [
    {id: 1, goal: 'Clean apartment', parent_id: null},
    {id: 2, goal: 'Clean bathroom', parent_id: 1},
    {id: 3, goal: 'Clean kitchen', parent_id: 1},
    {id: 4, goal: 'Clean sink', parent_id: 2},
    {id: 5, goal: 'Clean shower', parent_id: 2},
    {id: 6, goal: 'Make app', parent_id: null}

]

function buildTree(root) {
    return {
      goal: root.goal, // Store the goal
      children: tasks
        .filter(task => task.parent_id === root.id) // All tasks with parent_id  = root.id
        .map(child => buildTree(child)) // Recursively collect their children
    }
}

const result = buildTree(tasks[0]) // Build the tree starting with 'Clean apartment'
console.log(result);
```

You can simplify the logic somewhat by not passing around IDs

Answer (score 0):

Why is recursivity a requirement? You can use this iterative way

```js
function buildTree(tasks) {
  const tasksById = tasks.reduce((acc, task) => ({
    ...acc,
    [task.id]: { ...task }
  }), {})

  return Object.values(tasksById).reduce((tree, task) => {
    const parent = tasksById[task.parent_id]
    if (!parent) {
      return tree.concat(task)
    }

    parent.children = parent.children || []
    parent.children.push(task)
    return tree
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Because everything that can be done with recursion can be done with iteration, and vice versa, you need some other reason to choose one over the other for a particular problem.  I will go with elegance, which often means recursion, unless I find a performance issue with it.  Here, note how much simpler the answers using recursion are.